# VirtualBox error when updating

Tags: updates, 15.04, virtualbox, software-sources

Here is the error when I try and update:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/vivid/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'contrib/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here's the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-MATE 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422.1)]/ vivid main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Not the best soltuion, but deleting the following files from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` stopped the error: `oracle-vbox.list` `oracle-vbox.list.save`. Probably means VirtualBox won't update so not ideal.

Comment: May I ask how you are doing the update?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem where one of your sources is either outdated or corrupt to fix:

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

And then try the update again

Answer (score 0):

`(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)`

Try this Fix

delete the sources.list because its corrupt.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then re download a new one. by opening up software properties

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

tick the boxes: as below in the screen shot.  Change Main server to your Country. Then click Close

[image]

Then a another window will pop. you want to click on reload.

[image]

When thats done try to update